# how to format html tags fetching from xml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I need to format html tags comes from xml

example

```
<p><b>Location. </b> <br />Located in central Chennai, The Raintree Hotel,
Anna Salai is connected to the airport and close to U. S. Consulate, 
Valluvar Kottam, and Anna University.<p><b>Hotel features</b> 
Other points of interest near this luxury hotel include SDAT Tennis Stadium and    Kapalishvara Temple. </p><p><b>Hotel Features. </b><br />Dining options at The Raintree Hotel, Anna Salai include 2 restaurants. A swim-up bar and a bar/lounge are open for drinks. <p>
```

when i fetch this data from xml using simpleXML php it shows this type of data.I don't want this raw data.i need data like this

```
  Location
  Located in central Chennai, The Raintree Hotel, Anna Salai is connected to the airport and close to U. S. Consulate, Valluvar Kottam, and Anna University. Other points of interest near this luxury hotel include SDAT Tennis Stadium and Kapalishvara Temple.

 Hotel Features
   Dining options at The Raintree Hotel, Anna Salai include 2 restaurants. A swim-up bar and a bar/lounge are open for drinks. Room service is available 24 hours a day. The hotel serves a complimentary breakfast. Recreational amenities include an outdoor pool, a
```

I need the html formatted data showing in browser not html tags

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use [html-entity-decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) **if** you are controlling how the html is rendered. If not, you expose yourself to [Cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks.

You can work around this by either by changing the xml format to not require html tags (i.e. include a `<location>` and `<description>` tag or similar. If you get the html from an external party, try writing a parser yourself to safely extract just the parts you need.

Answer (score 0):

Well assign the value of xml to the `innerHTML` property of your target element. Thats it.. hope this helps you ...

Comment: i am using ajax jquery like innerHTML i am using html() function in jquery but it shows same data

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>

  .red { color:red; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <span>Hello</span>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
<script>$("div").html("<span class='red'>Hello <b>Again</b></span>");</script>

</body>
</html>`Sample to display the html string from jQuery documntation 1.4